# Unable to run zmap -- some *.so file not found

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation

I've installed zmap normally via pacman  and when I'm running it, I get:

```
zmap: /usr/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0: no version information available (required by zmap)
zmap: /usr/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0: no version information available (required by zmap)
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Arch Linux page for zmap](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/zmap/) shows the following dependencies:

> ```
> gmp
> hiredis
> json-c
> libmongoc
> libpcap
> byacc (make)
> cmake (make)
> gengetopt (make)
> pkg-config (make)
> ```

I'd suggest you install them:

```
pacman -S gmp hiredis json-c libmongoc libpcap byacc cmake gengetopt pkg-config
```

Comment: they should be installed along with zmap by the packet manager